# Can't insert into table if table already exists

Tags: python, mysql, database, class, mysql-connector

So I'm trying to insert a class variable into a mysql database and I'm having problems.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1050 (42S01): Table 'ordertable' already exists
```

This message pops up when i try to insert values into a table even when i know the table exists.

> order.py

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import connection
import mysql.connector
class MenuWindow():
def init(self):
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root", passwd="", database = "pizza")
    mycursor =db.cursor()

    orderData = [(None, self.varTotal.get())]

    for element in orderData:
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO ordertable (orderid,total) VALUES (?,?)", element)
    db.commit()
```

The table is created in this file

> connection.py

```
def get_connection():
db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root", passwd="", database = "pizza")

mycursor = db.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE orderTable (orderid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, total INT)")
```

Comment: If you create a table, it stays created. So you will have either create the table outside the code, or get the code to check if the table exists, so you only create it once

Comment: [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error message does not complain about the insert. It complains about the create, because connection.py attempts to create the table when it already exists.

You only need to create the table exactly once, you do not need to create it whenever you reconnect.

Remove the line of

```
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE orderTable (orderid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, total INT)")
```

Comment: I've already removed that line of code and it still says the same thing